# Access Token's query from JdbcTokenStore

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm new to **Spring Boot and Oauth** and I'm implementing Oauth Security on my system and I have doubts with **JdbcTokenStore queries**.

I've seen `DEFAULT_ACCESS_TOKEN_SELECT_STATEMENT = "select token_id, token from oauth_access_token where token_id =?"` in the **JdbcTokenStore** code.

I tried to get a token from oauth/token with client_id1 and I checked the token with client_id2, finally I received a successful response because it just filters token_id.

I was expecting an error like "token not found" or something similar.

Should this query has this behavior?

**UPDATE**

I have a **AuthorizationServer** and a **ResourceServer** separated, on my **AuthorizationServer** I'm getting ClientDetails from database and I have two entries:

[client_details_entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWgtR.png)

On my Web app, I'm using the first ClientDetails to get a valid token with:

`$ curl seiafiscalizacao:seiafiscalizacao123@localhost:8080/seia-auth-server/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d username=username -d password=pwd`

On oauth_access_token I got a new entry associating token_id with client_id:

[access_token_entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv6Eu.png)

On my **ResourceServer** I have a RemoteTokenServices with these configurations (second ClientDetails):

```
@Bean
@Primary
public RemoteTokenServices tokenService() {

    RemoteTokenServices tokenService = new RemoteTokenServices();
    tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("http://localhost:8080/seia-auth-server/oauth/check_token");
    tokenService.setClientId("seiafiscalizacao2");
    tokenService.setClientSecret("seiafiscalizacao123");
    return tokenService;
}
```

Finally, when I try to get any resource from my **ResourceServer** I'm getting success response even using different client_id:

[success_from_resourceserver_?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m86zO.png)

When I opened **JdbcTokenStore** code from `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store` I saw `private static final String DEFAULT_ACCESS_TOKEN_SELECT_STATEMENT = "select token_id, token from oauth_access_token where token_id = ?";`, and I figure out why I got success.

I'm not getting any error or exception, but I'm wonder about check my token with different client_id and get success.

Like I said before, I'm new in Oauth and I dont know if this was expected.

**To access ResourceServer I'm using RESTClient from Firefox**

**My SpringBoot version is 1.5.10.RELEASE**

**My application server is Wildfly 10.1**

By now my project is very complex to share, but if you need I can make a new with few things latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OAuth2 specification doesn't define that, see [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.3):

> **10.3.  Access Tokens**
>
> [...]
>
> This specification does not provide any methods for the resource server to ensure that an access token presented to it by a given client was issued to that client by the authorization server.

Hence, Spring Security OAuth2 doesn't check it.

Moreover, the `RemoteTokenServices` is a Spring Security OAuth2 feature and not covered by OAuth2 specification at all, see [OAuth 2 Developers Guide](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html)

> An alternative is the `RemoteTokenServices` which is a Spring OAuth features (not part of the spec) allowing Resource Servers to decode tokens through an HTTP resource on the Authorization Server (`/oauth/check_token`).